# PageableListView right arguments

Tags: java, wicket

I want to create a PageableListView with these arguments:

```
public PageableListView(final String id, final IModel<? extends List<T>> model
```

but the second argument `final IModel<? extends List<T>> model` confuses me abit. I have a list `List<Individual> individualList` which has some properties I want to use for the PageableListView I'm making. My problem is that I don't know how to cast it, or make it an acceptable argument.

Here is what I was working with:

```
 List<Individual> individualList = getIndividuals();
 WebMarkupContainer datacontainer = new WebMarkupContainer("data");
 datacontainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
 add(datacontainer);

PageableListView listview = new PageableListView("rows", individualList, 10) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item)
        {
            Individual individual = item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("individual_Id", String.valueOf(individual.getId())));
            item.add(new Label("name", individual.getFirstName()));

    };
    datacontainer.add(listview);
    datacontainer.add(new AjaxPagingNavigator("navigator", listview));
    datacontainer.setVersioned(false);
```

on the line with `Individual individual = item.getModelObject();` it gives me error with `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to IndividualCache`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PageableListView has a second constructor that just takes a `List<T>` as an argument:

```
PageableListView(String id, List<T> list, int itemsPerPage)
```

See: The [JavaDoc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/PageableListView.html#PageableListView(java.lang.String,%20java.util.List,%20int))

But you are already using that constructor, so there really isn't a problem here.
Your problem is that `PageableListView<T>` is a generic class, but you are using it as a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). That's why the method `getModelObject` will only return an `Object`.

Don't do that.

Instead use the generic argument to specify what kind of Objects your PageableListView is supposed to display:

```
 PageableListView<Individual> listview = new PageableListView<Individual>("rows", individualList, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer :)